# How to install ROS on Windows 10 - but not in C Drive?

Tags: windows, ros, chocolatey

I am following this guideline to install ROS Noetic via Chocolatey:

https://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

But it defaults to install in C drive which is what I don't want.

My C drive only has 2 GB remaining.

I want to install ROS in D drive.

Does it support to do so?

Comment: Easiest solution is to make a _junction_ from `c:\opt` to `d:\opt`. ROS won't notice that Windows silently translates all file paths.

Comment: [subst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) is the solution to this and similar issues (like paths that get too long, or contain characters that the software doesn't support, e.g. spaces).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the document, it is not recommended to install ROS in other drive.

> c:\opt is the required install location. Relocation is not currently
> enabled.

If you install in D drive, you need to replaced C:/ to D:/ inside files in opt folder, it is very likely to cause many unknown problems。